# Is it possible to store executable code into a table record using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

This is really more of a "Can I do it" theory question. Is it possible to store executive code within a column of a record for a table.

Lets put this into perspective of a table top card game transferred over to electronic media.
Say you have 4 players with a 20 hit points.

Naturally a record will represent a card.
Columns will be the quantity of a given card, Damage each card will deal, a string column for card descriptions, and lastly a column reserved for executive code for cards that represent special abilities.

When a card is played any executable code will effect outcome.

Comment: I just drew the *Greater Card of Incomprehension*

Comment: The blunt question is asking if it is possible to store executable code into a record of a table column.

Comment: You should choose the database you are interested in.

Comment: Usually one would store specific values that were analysed and acted upon but an independent executable process. You could store some kind of aggregated metadata or script like code but (imo) only as a last resort.  Storing some kind of  native binary code would be terrible.

Comment: Executed by what? It would be *possible* to store fragments of dynamic SQL or even binary data, yes, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: In MySQL stored procedures you do have the option of preparing a statement for a query from a variable, so that would depend on what kind of executable code you want to process (I suppose technically you might be able to prepare a statement that creates a complex procedure and then execute it). In php (for example) there is the eval function to execute code stored in a variable. However both are pretty nasty and I wouldn't recommend either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you?  Probably.  In virtually any database system, it would be possible to store a string of PL/SQL (for Oracle), T-SQL (for SQL Server), etc. that could be read and executed dynamically at runtime.

Should you?  Almost certainly not.  Building this sort of dynamism is rarely worthwhile.  It generally makes your system much more difficult to understand and debug since you now have bits of code as data in addition to the code that you're likely to actually look at.  It breaks all sorts of good programming practices (separating bits of related code some of which makes it into the code base proper and other bits of which get implemented in rows in a table, it inevitably causes you to expose methods to the world that you wouldn't if the system were designed properly, etc.) And it makes security much more complicated since you're essentially building in a wonderful SQL injection vulnerability into your system.  You do get much more flexibility but it's pretty rare that a system actually uses that flexibility often enough to offset the downsides.

Comment: I knew it would break any form of good programming practice imaginable. The idea was merely a what-if. Frankly I believe it to also be really inefficient since it would involve inserting code in strings, followed by having to parse it. Depending on the application though, there may be some use for such a practice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are trying to apply object-oriented design principles (data and functionality/methods encapsulated together) to a relational database.  If that is correct, then you might consider using PL/SQL packages in Oracle. The package would be a wrapper around the table, providing select/retrieve/insert/update/delete methods or functions, plus additional business methods that take a primary key value to identify which object (card) you want to operate on and then execute something based on that object's attributes (the column values of the row) and/or other parameters. Presumably the algorithm doesn't vary so much from card to card that it couldn't be generalized and parameterized. Fringe benefit, it will be manageable, compiled and cached for highest performance.
PL/SQL is not object-oriented, like Java or C++, but it does support encapsultation of object data attributes and related functionality.