# Render string with interpolation to HAML in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Lets say I have `"Today is #{Date.today}."` in my database. When I render the string in HAML I get the following:

```
%p entry.title
<!-- Current output -->
<p>Today is #{Date.today}.</p>
<!-- Expected output -->
<p>Today is Thu, 29 Jul 2021.</p>
```

Is there a way to tell HAML to render the string as Ruby code and not just as a string?

I know that if I do `%p Haml::Engine.new(entry.title).render` it works. But just want to know if there is maybe an easier/better way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you trust the people who are allowed to insert the string into the database? Or would it be possible that the strings might include potentially dangerous commands? For example that the string might include code to read database credentials or to delete the database?

Comment: @spickermann no one has access to the DB. Just regular string no dangerous commands.

Comment: Worth a read. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804481/2112512
Even if you could guarantee security (many would say, you can't), what if the Ruby code is invalid? I'd look for another solution if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I knew there could be some security issues but wanted to give it a try and see. I fixed it by just creating helper method to scan string for specific combination and replace it with what I want it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Kernel.sprintf` instead:

```
sprintf("Today is %s", Date.today)
```

It looks kind off in an OO language but thats because its a wrapper around the venerable C function which is widely known and has a pretty simple syntax for string interpolation. It does not have the risks of using eval.

Answer (score -3):

To evaluate Ruby in HAML, need `=` or `-`, [reference](https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-evaluation).

More common to use translation with variable in view, [reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations):

```
%p= entry.title
%p= t('today', date: Date.today)
```

And to store translation in yml:

```yaml
en:
  today: "Today is %{date}"
```

Or, if you wish, translation can be stored in DB with gem [globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize).

Comment: How is this even relevant to the question?

Comment: In question there is example of current output and expected output. Therefore, for me, it looks like question about translation with variable in HAML.